# Simulink STM32F4 support package contains corrupt .zip file

Tags: matlab, simulink, corruption, stm32f4discovery

I tried to install the STM32F4 support package on MAtlab 2014a, but it fails to install every time. I first tried to install it straight from the internet, when that failed i tried to download it again first, and then install it from folder, but that failed also, with the same error message:
(tl;dr it says the zip file stsw-stm32068.zip is corrupt.)

[image]
I tried to open this specific zip manually with winRar, and i got the same error from winRar saying the zip file was damaged. The other files opened without problems. I was convinced it was my fault at first, because such an error would be discovered and fixed quickly, since this hardware and probably also it's support package is widely used. But i tried it several times, and i get a corrupt zip file every time, so i guess it has to be a faulty package.

Does anyone know where to get a uncorrupted package, like an older release or something? It's a shame you can only download it via Matlab through a package installer. It'd be great if someone could send me this zip file, i can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Cheers

Comment: This is off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it.

Comment: Where should i post it then? Mathworks forum take ages to react, if they even do. I have found a solution to it though, so it may help other people with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on for some time and i found something, i opened the zip in Notepad and found HTML code, so i changed the zip's extension to .htm and it seems to be a fully functional HTML page.
I don't know why the .zip extension was given to it by Matlab.

SOLUTION:
I made a new fresh "stsw-stm32068.zip" file to replace the corrupt one,
and renamed the old corrupt zip file to "stsw-stm32068.htm" and placed this page in the new zip, and tried to install the thing.
I just guessed html file was the only one in said zip, with the same name as the zip itself. To my great supprisal the installation now succeeded.
I'll report this bug to Matlab.

I'm now stuck at the CMSIS folder validation in the installation procedure. I found a CMSIS folder and pointed it to that location, but it's v3.00 and v3.01 is required. This is only a matter of updating CMSIS folders, i'm sure it will install after.